# Not allowed duplicate record

Tags: firebase, data-modeling, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

It's a simple check to restrict duplicate entries, i can't find a way to do it, thought.

**Shema:**

```
{
  "languages": {
    "unique_id": {
      "code": "Fr",
      "name": "French"
    },
    "unique_id": {
      "code": "En",
      "name": "English"
    }
  }
}
```

**Security rule that i've tried:**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /languages/{language} {
      allow write: if !(resource.data.hasAny([request.resource.code]));
    }
  }
}
```

**For instance :this must not allowed**

```
{
  "languages": {
    "unique_id": {
      "code": "Fr",
      "name": "French"
    },
    "unique_id": {
      "code": "En",
      "name": "English"
    },
    "unique_id": {
      "code": "Fr",
      "name": "German"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really isn't a good way to do it with the current schema. Below are 2 methods with different trade-offs you could explore.

## Invert Data Model

Change your data model to make uniqueness the only option, which removes the need to validate.

```
{
  "languages": {
    "Fr": {
      "name": "French"
    },
    "En": {
      "name": "English"
    }
  }
}
```

Note in this model it isn't possible to add your broken case.

To query for any document with a particular language code, e.g. 'En', you can do:

```
.where("En.name", ">", "")
```

#### Pros:

- Non-unique language codes are impossible
- Simple to implement

#### Cons:

- You won't be able to do composite indexes on language code or name

## Post-validation

Alternatively, you can set up a Cloud Functions to trigger on any writes. This Function can then have code to do the uniqueness enforcement for you. It would then follow some logic you define if it detects an issue, such as either flagging the document as bad or removing & logging the subsequent non-unique entries.

#### Pros:

- You can do composite indexes with `languages.unique_id.code` and `languages.unique_id.name`

#### Cons:

- Incorrect data can exist for short periods of time
- Harder to give errors back to the client

## Post-Update

Rather than allowing clients to update the language codes, require them to write to a subcollection. Have Cloud Functions trigger on update to the sub-collection, then update the master document if it pasts your checks. Optionally you can then delete the document in the subcollection or leave it as an audit trail.

#### Pros:

- You can do composite indexes with `languages.unique_id.code` and `languages.unique_id.name`
- Document will always be correct

#### Cons:

- Data in the document can be stale for short periods of time
- Harder to give errors back to the client